# Is it possible to get path info in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When creating a new route in the maps there appears a small info about this route: how much time there you will need by car or on foot and the distance? Is it possible to get this info between two `LatLng` points?

Comment: Yes.  Look at the [DistanceMatrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) or the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/} (both also available through the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`DirectionsService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions).

You must request this service and parse the response. A simple route between 2 points contains  1 [`DirectionsLeg`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Legs) , where you'll find the desired details (e.g. `duration`  or `distance`)

Comment: is it possible to do with `php` ? Just do some curl requests?

Comment: Yes , the directionsService is also available as webservice: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/